# "We all know the climate changes, it has in the past, it is changing now"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> We all know the climate changes, it **has** in the past, it is
>   changing now and it will in the future, but what is different about
>   what we are doing now compared to what happened in the Cretaceous?

Would it have been more appropriate to use **had** in the sentence above? Does using the perfect here imply the repeatability of climate change  events, that they occurred many times before?

Comment: I have a bigger concern about the number matching: **changes** versus **it has**, **it is** and **it will**.

Comment: I suppose that "changes" here is a verb and "it" refers to "the climate".

Comment: Wow! I did not see that, but in this case a **that** was really welcome: "We all know **that** the climate changes...". Or maybe use semi-colon instead of comma after "changes"?  Verbally, the speaker can add intonation, but in writing... Tnx for the heads-up.

Comment: I agree. Plus, combining various tenses in a list, such as in the example above, seems to me (as a learner) to be a dangerous area. Just exploring the limits how to use them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put “had” it implies the change happened then stopped. Ie it was a “one off” change that was complete and finished.

Using “has” implies that the change was not a unique event and it can still change.

Comment: So,  if I used the present simple here,  it would **necessarily** mean that an event occurred only once in the past?

Comment: I mean,  it's now a matter of style,  right? The past simple just don't fit here?